# USB 3.0 Trouble

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, backup, rsync

I am using a WD Elements Portable 1TB USB 3.0 2.5" disk bought in May 2014 to backup data of my desktop machine. rsync runs smoothly without any error messages. However upon restoring data from the USB drive I found a large fraction of files with zero length. File system is ext4.

I tried fsck -f /dev/sdd2 and dd if=/dev/sdd2 of=/dev/null which never reported any errors. On my older machine using USB 2.0 I set up a loop rsyncing a 5GB directory, verifying with diff -r and deleting the directory without any errors during several hours of operation.

Problems arose with my new machine using USB 3.0. rsync -av did the copy silently without reporting any errors. However when checking the copies numerous files were found to have exactly zero length. Thus I am worried.

When buying the device I performed a frequent verification with diff -r during the first weeks and never detected any errors. After some time I stopped doing so and was really embarrassed finding the copying errors which occurred completely silently. 9,704 out of 823,872 files are exactly zero length, most of them jpegs or header files. The error is always the same: either the files copied are intact or zero length, no partial copies or changed bytes occur.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: I can't think of any way your issues can be related to USB 3.0. "Troubles with rsync" would make a lot more sense.

Comment: Wait, so for the first few weeks even `diff -r` did not report errors? And yet there actually were some? Or does the diff indeed detect the errors, indicating that at some point in time, the rsync stopped working correctly.

At any rate, I wouldn't yet eliminate USB 3.0, the USB-driver, or even ext4 as a source of error. 

Questions: (1) is there a hub between the host and device? (2) Is the cable specifically rated for USB 3? If not, it's a potential source of error (but only in general, not so specific an error as you seem to be having.)

Comment: (1) There is no hub (2) The cable came with the drive